# Bash unintentionally splitting command

Tags: bash, shell, command-line-arguments

Currently I had a rsync command which is failing once every ~15 minutes due to poor network condition. I had written a script to rerun the rsync, however the script does not work as intended because bash is unintentionally breaking up the command I passed in:

```
$ cat exit-trap.sh
#!/bin/bash
count=1

while :
do
        echo ==============
        echo Run \#$count
        $@
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] ; then
                exit
        fi
        echo Run \#$count failed
        let count++
        sleep 15
done

$ ./exit-trap.sh rsync --output-format="@ %i  %n%L" source::dir target
==============
Run #1
Unexpected remote arg: source::dir
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1348) [sender=3.1.1]
```

After poking around for a while I guess what rsync recevied in argv is `["rsync", "--output-format=@", "%i", "%n%L", "source::dir", "target"]. The output format is appearantly unintentionally splitted into indiviual pieces, causing a syntax error. Is there a way to fix this issue?

PS: So far I've also tried `sh -c $@`, `sh -c \"$@\"`, and

- `./exit-trap.sh rsync --output-format=\"@ %i  %n%L\" source::dir target`
- `./exit-trap.sh rsync --output-format=\\\"@ %i  %n%L\\\" source::dir target`
- `./exit-trap.sh "rsync --output-format=\"@ %i  %n%L\" source::dir target"`

None of these works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `"$@"` as described here https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#Special-Parameters:

> ($@) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" ….

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!